# Копировать значение ячейка A на другой лист, если ячейка B имеет оранжевую заливку. Apps Script

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Уважаемые знатоки, прошу у вас помощи. Пытаюсь перенести значение ячейки А (условно), на другой лист, если ячейка B имеет красную заливку. Со криптами в Гугл таблицах работаю не долго, так что могу не знать всех нюансов, но когда я пишу условие, при котором в ячейке B есть определенное слово, скажем «Брак», то все начинает работать как надо. Возможно я не правильно использую свойство getBackground… В общем, буду очень благодарен, если поможете.

```
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var list2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(«Брак на сортире Б5»);
var articl = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
var column = e.range.getColumn();
var row = e.range.getRow();
var lastRow = list2.getLastRow() + 1;
var colorRow = sheet.getRange(row, 9).getBackgrounds();

If(column === 9 && sheet.getName() === “Для сбора со стока»){
If(sheet.getRange(row, 9).getBackground() === “orange”){
list2.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(articl)
}
}
```

Comment: `.getBackground()` возвращает HEX код заливки, т.е. `красный` цвет, например, нужно указывать не `== "red"`, а `== "#ff0000"`. Ну и разберитесь с кавычками в коде

Comment: Не сработало( Кавычки исправил :)

Comment: а вы через `doEdit` делаете?

Comment: Через onEdit(e), если я правильно понял

Comment: `onEdit()` реагирует только на "прямое" изменение данных в ячейках. Данный триггер не будет срабатывать на изменение форматирования. Так что для вашей задачи он не подходит

Comment: Это же бот написал код. Он никогда не запустится

Comment: Функция onEdit, как раз таки, и подходит мне, так как данные из ячейки А должны переноситься на другой лист в момент, когда ячейка B окрашивается оранжевым цветом (т.е. происходит форматирование) Я поставил условное форматирование, что когда в ячейку B пишется слово «Брак», она окрашивается в оранжевый цвет и в этот момент браковый артикул товара должен копироваться и вставляться на другой лист.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что код, который вы предоставили, вообще не подходит для этого языка? Т.е. это не код, а белиберда. О чем вы дальше рассуждаете?

Comment: Я написал, что скрипты в Гугл таблицы пишу не давно, поэтому могут быть ошибку и мне необходима помощь, именно за этим я пришел. Может кто-нибудь написать код, который позволит мне переносить данные ячейки А в ячейку А на другом листе, если при этом ячейка B первого листа окрашена в оранжевый? Я предоставил код который у меня, при других условиях, идеально работает. Не знаю что вы называете белибердой…

Comment: `onEdit()` простой триггер, который срабатывает когда вы РУЧКАМИ меняете данные (не форматирование, не заливка, не уж тем более условное форматирование) в ячейках таблицы. Соответственно он вам НЕ подходит, об этом я вам писал ранее.

Comment: Я вас понял, попробую doEdit

Comment: В общем. У меня все заработало так, как нужно. Не хочу ставить под сомнения знания местных гуру, видимо apps script не очень популярен в этих местах, но ничего менять не пришлось. Скину пример своего когда, быть может кому-то будет полезно (мы ведь за этим здесь, чтобы помогать…)

Comment: ‘function onEdit(e){
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet() var column = e.range.getColumn()    var row = e.range.getRow()                 var articl = sheet.getRange(row, 5). getValue()                                               var list2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(«Имя листа куда нужно скопировать»)                 var lastRow = list2.getLastRow() + 1    If(column === 9 && sheet.getName() === «Лист1» && sheet.getRange(row, 10).getValue();){ if(sheet.getRange(row, 9)getBackground() === “#ff9900”){ list2.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(articl)}  }
}’

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e){ 
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
var column = e.range.getColumn(); 
var row = e.range.getRow(); 
var articl = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
var list2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(«Лист 2»); 
var lastRow = list2.getLastRow() + 1; 
if(column === 1 && sheet.getName() === «Лист 1» && sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();){ 
if(sheet.getRange(row, 2).getBackground() === “#ff9900”){
list2.getRange(lastRow,1).setValue(articl)
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]